# Magento add rate options to products

Tags: magento

i wanna add the option to vote for a product or give a rating, you know, the 5 stars, the user pick an amount, i don't know if i can do that in the backend, untill now, no result, i need someone to guide me with this, maybe i need a new module, or maybe just configure the backend and wow, its done.
thanks

Comment: I'm sure there is a plugin for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this [forum post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3699/).  Basically, you need to go to admin Catalog>Reviews and Ratings>Manage Ratings to set up the options for Ratings, and then assign them to your store view. The default templates should then show the Ratings html widgets.

Comment: hi jonathan, it is not unusual for me to expect an answer from you, thanks, you save my day again